# How to check if browser supports pseudo-elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a website that should run in ancient browsers (IE 7/8/9, Safari 5.1.7). Our target customer is the old people.

I'm no expert in javascript and I searched for solution. My title question is very straight-forward.

I used `input radio` and others that has custom design using before and after.

If it's checked. I just toggle in after and before display property in css.

The problem is when the user is using ancient browser, the input radio will never appear. My idea is toggle display in input radio if the browser doesn't support pseudo-elements.

Comment: "*Our target customer is the old people*". Why do you think old people use old browsers?

Comment: Because they're not always up to date, stuff works as is, and if you update it, and everything is *slightly* out of place, they 100% won't know what to do.

Comment: @RobG Even my momma doesn't know how to update browser. That's a good example for me. You cannot just choose the browser you want them to run. Right?

Comment: I have a client with +60,000 desktops that uses IE 8 because of technical debt from previous technology choices, nothing to do with how old they area or whether or not they *could* update their browsers. A similar client was using IE 6 until about 4 years ago for similar reasons (gotta love MS proprietary stuff).

Answer (score 2):

For CSS feature detection there really is no need to reinvent the wheel, tools like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download#setclasses) do this perfectly and have a very small footprint, since you can select only the feature detects that you need.

Seeing as you want to support IE <8, I would strongly advise you to use it, since you're probably going to run into a lot of situations where CSS/JS features are unavailable.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about Modernizr, +1. Been spoiled for a while with good behaving users apparantly haha.

Answer (score 0):

Detect if they have a sufficient browser: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Basically, IE8 (maybe 9 depending on what you need) and older don't work, everything else does.

Comment: We are still developing to IE 8 because that's what clients ask for.

Comment: We've educated our clients. We build for current browsers, and mayor functionallity will be workable for old browser, but the pretty stuff? Sorry, update.

Comment: I need script to check it so if the user is using old browser. I will show them the normal input radio :)

Comment: You can detect IE8 easily with JS :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find the library [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) useful in this instance. It allows you to test for browser features.

Optionally if you want to shim it so you know that the browser will support it you can use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)